# Changing 'consumptionState' for Google Android Developer API purchase

Tags: php, android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am writing the PHP back-end API for an Android application.  The Android sends me purchase token, product name, etc and then I make this call : [Purchases.products](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products#resource)

I then acknowledge the purchase using : [Purchases.products: acknowledge](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/acknowledge)

Then after successfully processing the transaction on PHP API side, I would need to change the 'consumptionState' of the transaction on Google Play side to indicate that this (consumable) product has been been consumed. But nowhere can I find any example of the call needed to change the 'consumptionState'. I use [google/apiclient](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) package for the interaction with Google Play.

Can someone point me in the right direction with regards to changing 'consumptionState' for a Google Play Billing purchase?

Comment: Hey! Were you able to find this doc anywhere? Or you went with marking it consumable from app(client) side itself?!